# urxvt -e emacs (nox) does not opening it correctly

Tags: emacs, urxvt

I have a little problem when opening emacs-nox in rxvt-unicode with the following command:

```
urxvt -e emacs
```

So, here is the window after running the command:
[Screenshot of emacs window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsNmk.jpg)

I have to maximize / unmaximize the window to set it normally.

I can not figure out where the problem is, if anyone knows?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the shortcut has nothing to do with the problem... confirmation please?

Comment: The problem happens when I open a ncurse program directly in urxvt

Comment: If I open urxvt and next running emacs, I have no bugs

Comment: So `urxvt -e emacs` has the same behaviour. You can edit your question if you want.

Comment: You're right. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add the tag `awesome-wm` back? I'm sure people using it already know the solution, but I can't remember what it is... And mention that the problem happens in `Awesome WM` in the text so that nobody gets confused please.

Comment: @lama02 I'm not able to reproduce this issue. Are you still seeing the problem?